# Is the usage of "will" proper in "Usually on Saturday, I will go to the store"?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

Is the following usage of "will" grammatical?

> Usually on Saturday, I will go to the store.

Comment: But since it's in the future tense and we can't speak about it with certainty, should we not use a conditional form like *would*?

Comment: @camelbrush That would make it past tense.

Answer (score 3):

It's grammatical, and means that you normally go to the store every Saturday.

Comment: How is it different with "Usually on Saturday, I go to the store."?

Comment: @Manoochehr. There's a subtle change in emphasis, which is difficult to expalain here. It depends on what has been going on previously in the conversation.

Comment: @Manoochehr, Barrie: I suspect the "subtle change in emphasis" relates to the fact that *will* is also a "verb of volition". Bearing in mind it's not making any meaningful reference to "future" in this example, I can easily suppose the difference to be that if you include *will*, you're increasing the implication that going to the store on Saturday is what you *want* to do (and thus usually *will* do, unless something prevents you).

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I'm sure that's part of it, but it will be prompted by what someone else has said.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more usual to say, "Usually on Saturday, I go to the store."  "I  will" is more about a future action than a recurring action.